# Permit same parameter for array and string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My user input has a `location` key, whose value can be an array:

```
params # => {"location"=>["California", "New York"], "email"=>"test@test.com", "name"=>"Test"}
```

or a string:

```
params # => {"location"=>"California", "email"=>"test@test.com", "name"=>"Test"}
```

I'm wondering what the best way is to permit an array or a string.

The cleanest way I can see is to add both `:location` and `location: []` as permitted parameters, but I'm not sure if this is the proper way to accomplish this.

```
def params
  params.permit(
    :name,
    :email,
    :location,
    location: []
  )
end
```

Any advice? Is this the correct way to do this?

Comment: You can change the parameters in the `params` method. But the solution you have right now is quite good

Comment: This will actually be a StackTooDeep error. The method `params` will have to be renamed.

Comment: By the way, a way to force a variable `x` to an array could be `[*x]`

Comment: Why can't it always be an array??

Comment: Did the answer below work out?

Answer (score 0):

Remember, `permit` is used to [whitelist parameters for Active Model mass assignment](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters). So your solution might be fine. Another way to do it is to force `location` into an Array (if it's already an array it will be unchanged):

```
def permitted_params
  params["location"] = Array(params["location"])
  params.permit(
    :name,
    :email,
    location: []
  )
end
```